# How to remove carriage return in python on eclipse IDE

Tags: python

I want to write a file by copying the contents of another file that has '\r' at the end of every line. I want to remove '\r' while writing to new file

file 1 (source)

input

input

output

file 2 (destination)

input

input

output

```
rf = open("file 1", 'r')
wf = open("file 2", 'w')
for line in rf:
    line = line.rstrip('\r')
    wf.write(line)
```

I tried the above code, but it didnt work. Please help

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: The line probably ends with '\r\n'.  Try `line = line.replace('\r', '')` instead.  Also, if your files are small enough, you might want to do it a file at a time.

Comment: I tried line. replace command too, but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for `open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`:

> When reading input from the stream, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. **Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller.** If it is '', universal newlines mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to the caller untranslated. If it has any of the other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.

So call `open("file 1", 'r', newline='\n')`.

Comment: could you please elaborate based on the given example?

Comment: Please help me in solving this issue

Comment: That *is* based on a line from your example. The first line where you opened "file 1".

Answer (score 0):

Guys I was able to solve the problem, The main thing we need to do is while reading and writing, it should be in "rb" other wise it wont work.

```
rf = open("file1", "rb").read()
newdata = rf.replace("\r\n","\n")
if newdata != rf:
    wf = open("file2", 'wb')
    wf.write(newdata)
    wf.close()
```